# Can I map/redirect routes to ports in the Ember FastBoot App Server?

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-fastboot

I would like to map specific ports to certain routes on [Ember FastBoot App Server](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot-app-server) so that I don't need a different url for different services.

Intended for production, I can not use development-only flags.

## Example

- `www.example.com:443` Ember FastBoot App Server (`4200`)
- `www.example.com:443/api/*` Node.js API (`8080`)
- `www.example.com:443/db/*` CouchDB (`5986`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can provide custom middleware](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/fastboot-app-server#pre-and-post-fastboot-middleware-hooks). Here you can provide middleware to proxy these routes for example with `node-http-proxy`.